# Apache Crashes AH00295: caught SIGTERM, shutting down[systemctl]

Tags: apache, systemctl

I built `apache-httpd-2.4.20` from the source and installed properly.

I have created `apphttpd.service` under `/etc/systemd/system`.

**Script**

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Web Server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=simple
TimeoutStartSec=600
PIDFile=/usr/local/apache/logs/httpd.pid
ExecStart=/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -k start
ExecStop=/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -k stop
ExecReload=/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -k graceful
Restart=on-abort
PrivateTmp=true
LimitNOFILE=infinity
#User=root
#Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

when i perform `systemctl start apphttpd`, got message started Apache Web Server,

**Status Log**

```
**systemctl status -l apphttpd**

apphttpd.service - Apache Web Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/apphttpd.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2018-06-13 21:45:20 SGT; 14min ago
  Process: 112124 ExecStop=/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -k stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 112118 ExecStart=/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -k start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 112118 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 13 21:45:20 <host> systemd[1]: Started Apache Web Server.
```

but the services are not started actually.

**error_log information:**

```
[Wed Jun 13 21:45:20.873135 2018] [core:debug] [pid 112123:tid 139709837686656] log.c(1546): AH02639: Using SO_REUSEPORT: yes (1)
[Wed Jun 13 21:45:20.873145 2018] [mpm_worker:debug] [pid 112123:tid 139709837686656] worker.c(1874): AH00294: Accept mutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
[Wed Jun 13 21:45:20.907675 2018] [core:info] [pid 112123:tid 139709837686656] AH00096: removed PID file /usr/local/apache/logs/httpd.pid (pid=112123)
[Wed Jun 13 21:45:20.907684 2018] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 112123:tid 139709837686656] AH00295: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

But if I start the service from /usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -k start, the services are started properly and able to get the response.

```
[Wed Jun 13 21:46:25.146698 2018] [core:debug] [pid 112229:tid 140320724187008] log.c(1546): AH02639: Using SO_REUSEPORT: yes (1)
[Wed Jun 13 21:46:25.146711 2018] [mpm_worker:debug] [pid 112229:tid 140320724187008] worker.c(1874): AH00294: Accept mutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
```

Is there any issue with my apphttpd.service script, any access issue ? Thanks for you suggestions and help in advance.

Comment: This should be on unix stackexchange

Comment: thanks zack, did there as well. @zack6849